Should we change the text on our comment link?
I wanted to ask you people whether you agree with the following suggestion:
Should we change the link-text of the link that lets us add comments from "Add a comment" to "Improve this post" instead?
This has been done on other sites and it can work wonders with regards to the tendency to have long comment threads that do few beyond throwing opinions (or answers) around where they simply do not belong as per our guidelines.

It feels like a bit of a band-aid solution, when the problem is that people want to discuss something, but doing so in the appropriate place (chat) involves a whole lot of steps. But I guess band-aids are sometimes useful, so idk.

@NotThatGuy "bandaid" is a good analysis of the proposal.

Ive given (my version of) why bandaid below. Pls see

@NotThatGuy I'd not see it as bandaid but rather one first step and measure among a bunch of others necessary.

What if there were also a simple link that a user with decent rep could click, "Start chat room linked to this post," or (maybe) even "Migrate comments to chat"?  I saw an option like this once (first option), but I haven't seen it since.

Can we give it a trial period and then assess how it went after an agreed upon time, say six months?

@PeterRankin See also: Should "move-to-chat" be provided on demand (as a button perhaps)?, Let's make it easier to get a room and Can we have an easier way to set up a chat room from a post?. The "start chat room" prompt shows up after you've posted something like 4-5 comments on a post (maybe also to a specific person).

Thanks for those links @NotThatGuy, I'm glad to see others have brought up the same kind of thing.

@NotThatGuy Aye, sadly the chat room offer only pops up in back-and-forth discussions using tags.

In a vote like this, are users intended to upvote the answer they favor, and downvote the other answer(s)? Or only upvote the answer they favor, without downvoting others?

@user509184 Users are intended to vote they way they deem appropriate, like responsible independent adults  Voting behaviour really isn't something anyone should regulate as long as it is not getting personal IMHO.

@PhilipKlöcking You have presumably made this post to gather information about user preferences. I am saying that I do not know how you intend for users to report their preferences. I'm not asking you to regulate anything, just asking how you intend for users to report their preferences: an upvote and a downvote, or an upvote only. If some users vote in the first way, and others in the second way, it is much less clear what the results of the vote actually mean about users' preferences. Specifically, I am not sure whether I am supposed to downvote the answer(s) I disagree with.

@user509184 In the end, this is a (popularity) vote about a particular measure that will probably change the way the site is used. Accordingly, I think all options are valid since the votes should reflect the users' stance on the matter. Thus, if someone merely says "Sounds good" and gives an upvote for yes, this is just as valid as someone thinking "Can't stay as it is" and adding a downvote to no. This way, the outcome more realistically reflects the actual stance of the community IMHO.

@PhilipKlöcking "This has been done on other sites and it often works wonders"--if you remember other sites, I think which ones would be helpful to include. (Reasoning: my first inclination is "people won't be fooled by the label, it's the comment box because it acts like the comment box." But if it's worked on some site, I'm willing to consider that evidence.)

@Kaia See here

The rule I use for upvotes and downvotes on SE is "does this contribute to the conversation". I only downvote if I feel that something is flat out wrong, off topic, or incoherent. I upvote if I think it was useful, sometimes even if I disagree with it. On comments, though  I tend to upvote only if I agree. Note that this comment may or may not satisfy my own criteria....

Yes
This will hopefully help people to use comments for their intended purpose more often.

It appears that the button to create a chat has had its auto-threshold reduced below 20.  The combo of this change, plus the easier auto-chat, will I believe more easily allow for chat dialogs, plus leave actual improvement recommendations visible with the question/answer.

Subtle changes in language certainly can be productive.

No
It's fine as it is and I do not want this change to happen.

I have to status-decline this one. We ran a test on Workplace and IPS in 2018 to see how this impacted comments. After those tests were concluded, the comment button text was changed back to where it was previously, and no network site has implemented it since.
This is not a customization that we currently offer for sites.

I don't quite understand this line of argument. The experiment was deemed successful and actually, it is still online on IPS.SE. The same holds for TheWorkspace (both on main sites only, of course). They kept the change. Thus, I have to object the reasoning.

I don't know where you are seeing this, but it's not currently live on IPS or Worklpace. It was turned off in 2019.

Funny, it shows "Improve this post/answer" as long as I'm not part of the community. Changes to "add comment" after I joined. Apologies.

Bandaid from @nottthatguy is a good summary of the proposal.
In expanded form
I believe SE is based on the following escalation path. To the extent we adhere to it we are in sync with the SE structure, both in intention and in fact.
1. Fundamental Modus Operandi
On an SE site in the ideal situation all that should happen  are these 4 activities:

Ask a question
Answer a question
Upvote
Downvote

Basically learn/educate and move on.
But...
2. Clarifications
Communications are not perfect in the real world, questions need clarifying. Answers too may need to be amended.
Hence comments come in;
And (suggested) edits.
Important Note:
The help says:
»Do not comment for answering a question«
3. Above fails but democracy still succeeds
Something goes off the rails, something wildly inappropriate gets in and needs addressing.
The event is abnormal but the process is still normal (democracy), viz. the community close vote/delete answer is invoked and functions appropriately.
4. None of the above works
Things can go off the rails and in a loop.
There is no convergence.
The moderator steps in an takes an “extraordinary action”
Analysis of the above
The above works, kinda,sorta at least on the technical sites starting with SO (original), superuser, askubuntu.
It begins to fail more and more as we go from "hard" subjects to "soft" ones [hard/soft in the sense of exact vs arts/humanities] because discussion is far more central on these than bald facts.
Out of all these it fails most abysmally on phil-SE.
[eg. I've not seen much problem on music-SE]
For a number of reasons:

The demarcation problem is huge here compared to near nonexistent on the technical sites. eg. a windows question on ubuntu — trivial; a politics question on law — not so trivial but sill within reach etc. But with philosophy: What is philosophy? is a core question! If we accept that the demarcation problem is by definition highly nontrivial
Philosophy ≠ Philosophy by law
We are not philosophers
Cheating
Using VTC as a costless downvote

Solution?
I have my thoughts of course on solution(s).  Will refrain for now until there is some convergence on diagnosis.
